# How can I stop growing child elements for a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<div>` element that has multiple `<img>` elements in it.

The user can add more `<img>` elements to this `<div>` element, but I want to limit the total number of `<img>` elements contained in the `<div>` to ten.

To accomplish this I want to use a script that will make images that come after the tenth image display to "none". Can anyone help me?

Comment: NEI: what is being used to add the `img` tags?

Comment: ^ what @cwallenpoole said. It's better to hide them as they're added or prevent them from being added in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count elements with [jquery count](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

And then a simple:

```
 if($("img").next('img').length > 10)
   next('img').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fitting them into the div with sizes correct as to force the div to only be able to hold 10 images, and then no more will fit, you can add to the div's style something like this:

```
    width: widthOfFiveImages;
    height: heightOfTwoImages;
    overflow: hidden;
```

That would force all other images to be hidden inside the div.

Comment: This assumes the widths of all the added images will/can be known.

Comment: Or they can be put into nested div's with the images inside, with the nested div's having a set height and width.

But you are correct, it would require you to know the height and width that the images will take up.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a case of good CSS rules than a case of jQuery magic.

You can do this with nth-child selectors:

```
#div-id > img:nth-of-type(n+11) {
    display: none;
}
```

See [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/milieu/pen/Kjpwq) for an illustration.

Comment: should not it be n+10 since we are not trying to add after 10 ?

Comment: @vamsi For n = 0, (n+10) = 10. We still want the tenth <img> to show up. Therefore we start at n+11. You can play around with the CodePen to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `gt` selector...

```
$('#yourdiv').find('img:gt(9)').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Considering your div has "container" as its ID, you can check with this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
if(container.getElementsByTagName("img").length < 10) {
    // allow appending new img
}
```